# How to concatenate value in database column on update in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to add last name on update with first name; first name is already in column but I want on update first name+last name

This is my event handler code

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Record REC = new Record();
    REC.ID = Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text);

    int id = REC.ID;
    REC.Name= TXTNAME.Text;

    String updatedname=REC.Name;
    RecordFactory FAC = new RecordFactory();

    if (FAC.Update1(id,updatedname))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("update");
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("not");
    }
}
```

This is connection code between handler and query

```
public bool Update(int id, String name)
{
    return rd.Update(id, name);
}
```

This is query code

[AS UPDATE call concatenate last name with first name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8HLw.png)

[before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSj6M.png)

```
public bool Update(int id ,String name)
{
    Record REC = red.Records.Where(X => X.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (REC != null)
        REC.Name =String.Concat(REC.Name+name);

    return red.SaveChanges() >0;
}
```

Comment: Do you get any value for REC after the query?

Answer (score 0):

To update a record, you need to set the Entity state to modified.

```
public bool Update(int id ,String name)
{
    Record rec= red.Records.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    if (rec!= null)
    {
       rec.Name =String.Concat(REC.Name+name);

       db.Entry(rec).State = EntityState.Modified;

       return red.SaveChanges() >0;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`EntityState` is defined in `Microsoft.Data.Entity` namespace. You need to import that namespace to your class.with `using Microsoft.Data.Entity` statement.